# Pro*C Code handling to solve ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL

Tags: c++, c, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-pro-c

I have a Pro*C code that connects to Oracle database and runs SQL query as needed.
A simple SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT A, B FROM TBL1 WHERE A = 'a'
```

faces an error  `ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL`
Note in TBL1, A is defined as VARCHAR2(30) and B is NUMBER(4,2).
My Pro*c version is  `Pro*C/C++: Release 11.2.0.3.0` 
And I am using GNU gcc family of compiler g++ version 2.95.3.
Oracle documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/api/doc/PC_22/ch03a.htm) states that

```
if you SELECT or FETCH a null into a host variable that has no indicator, Oracle issues the following error message:

ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL
```

One suggested remedy is: we can specify UNSAFE_NULL=YES to disable ORA-01405 message while running Pro*c but when I try to add that flag with proc command, it says,  UNSAFE_NULL=YES allowed if MODE=ORACLE and DBMS=V7 or V8

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Use indicator variables....

Answer (score 3):

Been years since I did any Pro*C, but I remember when I first came across this in an earlier version  of Pro*C, and you had to use indicator variable to check if the value was NULL or not. That changed however when Oracle introduced the STRING datatype. I liked this so much I even started to TO_CHAR numbers and store them to   STRING.

See this from that document you linked to:

> > STRING
>
> The STRING datatype is like the VARCHAR2 datatype, except that a
>   STRING value is always null-terminated.
>
> On Input Oracle uses the
>   specified length to limit the scan for the null terminator. If a null
>   terminator is not found, Oracle generates an error. If you do not
>   specify a length, Oracle assumes the maximum length of 2000 bytes. The
>   minimum length of a STRING value is 2 bytes. If the first character is
>   a null terminator and the specified length is 2, Oracle inserts a null
>   unless the column is defined as NOT NULL; if the column is defined as
>   NOT NULL, an error occurs. An all-blank value is stored intact.
>
> On Output Oracle appends a null byte to the last character returned.
>   If the string length exceeds the specified length, Oracle truncates
>   the output value and appends a null byte. If a null is SELECTed,
>   Oracle returns a null byte in the first character position.

Answer (score 0):

Using indicators for null detection:

short idxA, idxB;

FETCH ... INTO :varA :idxA, :varB :idxB;

Then indicator is set to -1 if the value is NULL;